# High load+fanspeed with low mem/cpu consumption after update 22.04

Tags: 22.04

After I have been running the updates today for Ubuntu 22.04, I got an issue where my laptop has a high load between 1.6 and 2.0 on idle, even after killing nearly every process. Memory consumption looks good, CPU consumption feels bit high, but the laptop is still getting hot and fans are running overtime.

I've tried restarting and using the previous used kernel, but no effect.

What could be the cause and how to fix this issue?

Specs and info (let me know if I need to add more).

- Dell Precision 5540
- UHD Graphics 630
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9850H CPU @ 2.60GHz

[image]

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log
<cropped>
Start-Date: 2023-09-19  09:14:49
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.16959'
Remove: linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-32-generic:amd64 (6.2.0-32.32~22.04.1), linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-32:amd64 (6.2.0-32.32~22.04.1), linux-modules-6.2.0-32-generic:amd64 (6.2.0-32.32~22.04.1), linux-image-6.2.0-32-generic:amd64 (6.2.0-32.32~22.04.1), linux-headers-6.2.0-32-generic:amd64 (6.2.0-32.32~22.04.1)
End-Date: 2023-09-19  09:14:52
```

```
uname -r  # Running newly installed kernel
6.2.0-32-generic

uname -r  # Restart and used older kernel
6.2.0-26-generic
```

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version  
1.21.0
```